# Manhua about a prince who dies from illness and is revived as a kind of 'zombie' by a 'magician'

Tags: story-identification, manga

The manga is about a prince who was very sick and dies. He is caught by a "magician" who revives him and starts to experiment on him. He becomes a kind of 'zombie,' but the protagonist is still aware that he is alive. After a while, he begins to have control of his own body and trains to kill the magician who revived him.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Is this ***[The Undead Lord Of The Palace Of Darkness](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series/ricn5zm/kuraki-kyuuden-no-shisha-no-ou)***...?

> ...I don't want to die. I want to be free.
> If a monster is what I have to become to be free, then that is what I will resign myself to.
>
> Striking the infected with incessant pain that runs throughout the body, a strange, debilitating, and deadly illness. The life of the boy who had suffered several years with this affliction had come to end with little time for him to despair as he died without an attendant by his side. When he awoke again, he had been made into the lowest ranked undead by an evil necromancer. Though the boy rejoiced at having obtained a body that could not feel pain, he immediately realized that he was still at the mercy of others. There was no large difference between his present situation and being confined in bed. However, the world could not leave the boy alone when he wished to be at peace.
>
> With freedom as his goal, what he needed was prudence and power. Occasionally running, fighting, fearful, and hesitant, this is the story of the cowardly King of Undead as he seeks to be free.

A young lord dies from an incurable illness, having spent most of his life on a sickbed. His corpse is subsequently obtained by a necromancer, who resurrects him as a 'fleshman' in order to use him as a slave.

The main character retains his full intelligence and memories, and is stronger and more mobile in this form than he was when he was alive. He initially conceals his intelligence and growing strength from the necromancer, and secretly reads books on necromancy, plotting whether to remain with the necromancer or kill him and run.

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's the same one thank you very much I've been looking for it for a long time and I couldn't find it at all